# Mysql foreach with condition depends on other table record

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, foreach

I have 2 table.

`t1` and `t2`.

`t1` was storing maps infomation.

`t2` was storing some extra information for `t1`

`t1` table as below:

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| ID     | maptitle  | item1     | item2      |item.$x    |
+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| 1      | Amap      | 1000      | 2000       |x          |
| 2      | Bmap      | 2000      | 3000       |x          |
| 3      | Cmap      | 3000      | 4000       |x          |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

the `itemx` is depends on how many rows in `t2`
`t2` table as below:

```
+----------+----------------+
| ID       | title          |
+----------+----------------+
| 1        | extra1         |
| 2        | extra2         |
| x        | x              |
+---------------------------+
```

First, My script when I `insert` a new data to `t2`, the `t1` will add `item.$x`. `$x` is the ID of `t2`. But I face a problem when I `query` data and my coding now as below:

```
$mapslist = DB::fetch_all("SELECT * FROM ".DB::table('t1')." ORDER BY id ASC");
foreach($mapslist as $mn => $ml){
    $mapslista[] = $ml;
}
```

My output coding in html:

```
<!--{loop $mapslista $mn $ml}--> //This is looping in my html
    <div>{$ml[id]} , {$ml[maptitle]} {$ml[item.$x]}</div>
<!--{/loop}--> //Looping END

//below is what I guess
<!--{loop $mapslista $mn $ml}--> //This is looping in my html
    <div>{$ml[id]} , {$ml[maptitle]} , <!--{loop again}-->{$ml[item]}, {$ml[item2]} {$ml[item3]} <--{/loop}--></div> //the $ml[item.$x], the $x is depend on how many row in t2
<!--{/loop}--> //Looping END
```

Final output as below (html):

```
1 , Amap
2 , Bmap
3 , Cmap
```

My question is, how if my `t2` only got `ID 1`, then `t1` only show the `item1` data? If my `t2` got `10 rows data`, then `t1` only show the `item1` until `item10` data?

Below is what I expect: (example if `t2` only 1 row, my `t1.item` also should have `item1`)

```
1 , Amap , 1000
2 , Bmap , 2000
3 , Cmap , 3000
```

example if `t2` have 2 rows, then my `t1.item` also should have `item1` `item2` column. so the final output should be

```
1, Amap , 1000 , 2000
2, Bmap , 2000 , 3000
3, Cmap , 3000 , 4000
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please include your desired output.

Comment: I have edit my question, please have a look, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question well, but don't you need to simply join tables?

```
$mapslist = DB::fetch_all("SELECT * FROM ".DB::table('t1')." AS t1 LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('t2')." AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.item.$x ORDER BY t1.id ASC");
foreach($mapslist as $mn => $ml){
    $mapslista[] = $ml;
}
```